# Woocommerce product pages blank?

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, woocommerce, product

I am having a strange problem where my product pages are blank most of the time in woocommerce. If you click a product, sometimes it may or may not load, and if it doesn't, you have to refresh it multiple times until the page finally shows the content. I noticed this only happens to users who are not logged into wp-admin.

I had W3 caching plugin but I deactivated and deleted and the problem still persists? I am not sure how this started... I am using the most updated version of woocommerce.

Website: http://museiam.ca/

I would appreciate any help as I'm quite stumped.

Comment: Are you sure you are giving the page time to load? I notice there there is a loading bar and sprite at the top of the page, but if you scroll down a bit they disappear and it does look like the page has stopped loading.

Comment: The loading bar wrapper is just not fixed, so when you scroll it will disappear. I am giving it time to load, as the loading bar completes and the page is blank. The header and footer still show however not the product content. Not sure why :(

Comment: Hi again. I took a look at my error log and came accross this "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace." Would this in anyway have something to do with it? I can post more of the error log if you wish!

Comment: I also noticed this error in my error log. I am sure it is one of the two. "ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 1). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/eig_rules.conf"] [line "237"] [id "900177"] [msg "Brute Force Attempt HTTP 1.0 w/o Accept Header"] [hostname "www.dynamic-gym.com"] [uri "/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php"] [unique_id "VK2yg0KT9KIAACE4cM4AAAVA"]"

Answer (score 2):

### Issue #1 - Failing to load, redirect loop

According to your comments about the error logs the product page is doing a redirect to itself, and getting stuck in that loop. This explains the "10 internal redirects" error message. The access log error is likely just a side effect of having so many of the same repeat requests in such a brief time window.

Note that I could not reproduce this issue, but I got a very similar issue (below). I was unable to determine why this is happening through poking around. This may take some code investigation (aka, on your end). Is this a custom WP theme?

### Issue #2 - Loading complete, but not displayed

A second type of error occurs which is similar. Middle-click or open a product in a new tab. Or click on a direct link to a product, such as: http://museiam.ca/product/black-cut-sleeve-sweater/

The content will load, but it will be a white page. In this case, the javascript has loaded content but did not complete the loading event to make it visible.

You can confirm the second issue by opening your dev tools (for chrome: F12), and entering the following javascript into the script console:

`jQuery('.global_content_wrapper').css('opacity', 1)`

This should make the content visible.

**EDIT:** It seems issue #2 is also inconsistent, sometimes it does work - though much less often than following a link from within the website. These two issues may be one in the same.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the reply. I was playing around with some plugins which is why you may have seens tons of code.. I tried the js and it seemed to load the content, however sometimes without the descriptions like you said. When you delete your cache then click a product, it will work fine. However, if you try to reload the page or access the same product again it will show blank. I'm stumped and have no clue as to why this is? I'm, thinking its a cache issue or something, as this started only happening recently & I've really only been doing minor css tweaks. I even deleted w3tc with no luck

Comment: I am also using a child theme of the theme "The Retailer". However I never had this problem before and I'm not sure it is theme related, again, it just happened yesterday and I've only been doing minor css tweaks. I did play with w3tc a bit but I completely removed it and the problem still persists. So you are saying it is not related to the error in the error log? Thx!

Comment: Ah ok, that explains the content problem. The loading issue seems to only pop up if *something* is missing. I believe that something is caused by a script error. When the content doesn't load, a JavaScript error is thrown that explains `NProgress is undefined`. On pages where it loads successfully, NProgress is defined. Hopefully that helps, you might try your dev tools and see what other errors might pop up.

Comment: Hello. what do you think is missing that is causing this problem to happen? Is it the tab descriptions? Could it be caused by a css error or syntax issue? do you know how I can go about solving the problem or what I should look at more closely because really I have no clue lol

Comment: Hello again. After more testing it seems the issue was just caused by a plugin that was causing conflicts with other plugins. After deactivating that plugin the problem is has completely disappeared and product pages load fine.. Thanks for your help though!